# paint.setAlpha() not working as expected

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custom FadingColor transition from a solid color to an actual screen of my application,

I have a canvas to draw on, and I draw the screen with

```
// int alpha is ensured to stay in [0,255] range...
alpha -= 1;
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
//then I draw a circle in the middle
//...
canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(alpha,255,255,255));
```

(I'm well aware of the canvas being double buffered and I do draw the screen every frame, but still it flickers..)

The thing I cannot understand is that while the screen flickers in the animation, the background which is literally argb(alpha,255,255,255) over argb(255,255,255,255) is rendered light gray in some frames !!

I just want to understand how is this even possible ? how can a semi-transparent white make a white background less white ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

First, I think the problem has to do with the ColorFilter Mode, (or PorterDuff.Mode), when applying two colors with alpha component, they do not mix by 'ADD' by default. NOTE, I still don't fully understand why, maybe someone could explain in details..

The (trick) solution (since PorterDuff.Mode is not supported in lower APIs) I used a Shader (a LinearGradient with the only one color)

```
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0,0,100,100,Color.argb(alpha,red,green,blue),
Color.argb(alpha,red,green,blue), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

This solution fixed the flickering and the weird color combinations that were showing in the animation.